# Gmail screws up html emails that I send out

Tags: html, css, gmail

This code for a HTML email renders nicely in all clients except gmail.  For some reason, the link is not underlined, so the reader doesn't realize its a link.  Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Thanks!

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration:underline;" href = "http://www.example.com/">Click</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration:underline;" href = "http://www.example.com/">Click</a></td>
```

To

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.example.com/">Click</a></td>
```

So remove the spaces between your `href` and the link.

Answer (score 1):

From my email experience, sometimes the client will do some pretty awful things and you can't do anything about it. Have you tried either using !important or declaring your styles in a style block at the top of your html?

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend maybe bolding the link :\

Comment: I don't believe the problem is underlining the link, the problem is that Gmail doesn't recognize it's a link, if it recognizes it then it will be underlined automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If by gmail you mean the email inbox you access from your browser, I think you are going to need to look at the default display settings from your browser and the gmail account. Maybe move the `text-decoration:underline;` from the `a` tag to the `td` tag as well and see if that changes something.

This [link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) may also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. Gmail may have not recognized the spacing you had between
href = "yourlink". I can't think of any other reason why it wouldn't have worked. I code html emails everyday and always test for gmail.

`<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;">
<a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;" href="http://www.example.com/">Click</a></td>`

Another option to do is rearrange the code a bit by appending the style after the link. Like below.

`<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;">
<a href="http://www.example.com/" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;">Click</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Designing HTML e-mails sucks. It's official. It always makes me feel dirty! :P

That said, it's always a compromise getting HTML e-mails working across the board - until we get standards-compliance across the board there will always be compromises.

A few suggestions though, some may be a bit clunky but that's the nature of this particular beast...

The odd thing is, it should underline by default so you shouldn't need to specify it using inline CSS. Are you sure you haven't got a contradictory style declaration elsewhere that's overriding this inline one?

Remove the white-space from the element attributes

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.example.com/">Click</a></td>
```

try wrapping the text in a `<span>` and stick the underline on that instead

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.example.com/"><span style="text-decoration:underline;">Click</span></a></td>
```

if all else fails, change the style of the link to make it more obvious to the reader that it is a link

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#337711" style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #fcff01;font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;" href="http://www.example.com/">Click</a></td>
```